# How to find out the amount of lines of documents in a folder using shell scripts?

Tags: macos, shell

I have a folder full of my code, what shell script can I use to find out the total amount of lines of code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very simple solution would be `wc -l ./*`, which counts the number of lines in all files, as well as each file individually.

If you want something more sophisticated, use [sloccount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/). You can install it e. g. using [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew):

```
brew install sloccount
```

Run it on the folder containing the code, like this:

```
sloccount .
```

It'll give you lines by programming language and directory.

Comment: If you want per-file counts as well as a total: `wc -l ./*`

Comment: I think `brew sloccount` hasn't worked for a while because http://www.microbrew.org/tools/md5sha1sum/md5sha1sum-0.9.5.tar.gz that the sloccount formula requires hasn't been available for some time.

Comment: `sudo` is unnecessary (and not advisable) when installing homebrew packages.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to count the number of lines in text files, try `wc -l *`.